# SQL DML SCRIPTS

Tags: mysql, sql

For a given period (bounded by two given dates inclusive), say 01 December 2002 to 31 July 2003, 
find the set of the people who have at least one EZ link card issued within the specified period. For 
EACH person in the set, list the (i) Owner NRIC, (ii) the total number of his/her cards issued during 
the period, and (iii) total number of card replacements (till current date) that have been made by the 
owner for only those cards that were issued during the given period. List your results in ascending 
order of Owner NRIC.

```
create table card
(
CardID  int not null primary key,
OwnerNRIC   char(9),
IssuedDcardate  date,
StoredValue decimal (5,2),
OldCardID   int,
constraint card_fk foreign key (OldCardID) references card(CardID)
);
```

As above is my card table.

This is my attempt at it but i was pretty lost.

```
 Select distinct(ownerNRIC) as NRIC,count(*) as Total Crads Issued during Period
From card
Where issuedDate between ‘2002-12-01’ and ‘2003-7-31’ group by ownerNRIC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a card replacement results in a non-null OldCardId.  If OldCardId is NULL, then this was *not* a card replacement.  Take advantage of the way COUNT(*expr*) ignores rows where *expr* is NULL.

```
SELECT ownerNRIC AS NRIC, 
  COUNT(*) AS `Total Cards Issued During Period`,
  COUNT(OldCardID) AS `Card Replacements During Period`
FROM card
WHERE issuedDate BETWEEN '2002-12-01' AND '2003-7-31' 
GROUP BY ownerNRIC;
```

You were using DISTINCT incorrectly.  It's not a function, and it's unnecessary anyway because ownerNRIC was your GROUP BY column.

> total number of card replacements (till current date) that have been made by the owner for only those cards that were issued during the given period

This requirement is not clear.  Do you mean the old card was issued during the given period, and the new card was issued anytime up to the current date?  If so, the query above won't give you that.

Comment: Hi,I am still having a syntax error in this line
  COUNT(OldCardID) AS Card Replacements During Period.
SQL is seriously so tough and require lots of brain workkk

Comment: For example, person S1111111 has 5 cards C1 (issued on 2 Jan 2001), C2
(issued on Dec 11 2002), C3 (issued on July 20 2003 as a replacement for C1), C4 (issued on July 21 
2003 as a replacement for C2), and C5 (issued on August 2 2012 as a replacement for C4). I couldn't figure out what it is asking.

Comment: I fixed a missing comma in my example query above, sorry about the mistake that caused the syntax error.  I need to be away for some time, I'll consider your other comment later.